# UIButtonTypeSystem on iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums, uibutton

Is the following valid on iOS 6 using Xcode 5 and the latest compiler?

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
```

`UIButtonTypeSystem` seems to resolve to the same thing as `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect` on iOS 6 as well as iOS 7 if I'm not mistaken but I may be misreading this.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIButtonType) {
    UIButtonTypeCustom = 0,                         // no button type
    UIButtonTypeSystem NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0),  // standard system button

    UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure,
    UIButtonTypeInfoLight,
    UIButtonTypeInfoDark,
    UIButtonTypeContactAdd,

    UIButtonTypeRoundedRect = UIButtonTypeSystem,   // Deprecated, use UIButtonTypeSystem instead
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to support iOS 6 then simply use `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect` instead of `UIButtonTypeSystem`. Then it will work under both iOS 6 and 7.

Comment: Yes, but what about the other way around?

Comment: iOS 6 knows nothing about `UIButtonTypeSystem`. It might work if under iOS 6, `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect` happens to have the same integer values that `UIButtonTypeSystem` has under iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

The docs are your friend. Searching under `UIButtonTypeSystem`, we find:

> UIButtonTypeSystem A system style button, such as those shown in
>   navigation bars and toolbars. **Available in iOS 7.0 and later**.

So no, UIButtonTypeSystem is new in iOS 7. Results for older OS versions will be undefined.

Comment: Yes, but in Xcode 5 `UIButtonTypeSystem` still works with a Deployment target of iOS 6 and a base SDK of iOS 7 when running on iOS 6 which lead to confusion.